# Простой вопрос про классы

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы

подскажите в чем ошибка? Почему self не определен?

```
class mono(object):
    """docstring"""

    def __init__():
        self.url, self.headers, self.session = login()
        



    def login():
        self.url = '12345'
        self.headers = '12345'
        session = '12345'
        return self.url, self.headers, self.session




    def get_df_1(self, url=self.url, headers=self.headers, session=self.session):
        print(self.url)
        print(self.headers)
        print(self.session)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5):

Тут `def __init__():` и тут `def login():` нет аргумента `self`.

Вообще, во все методы нужно `self` писать. Есть 2 исключения:

- Статичные методы. Для них к методам добавляется декоратор [staticmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod)
- Методы класса. Для них к методам добавляется декоратор [classmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) и вместо `self` используется `cls`

---

Нельзя в значениях по-умолчанию указывать `self` самого класса, это вещь доступна только внутри методов:

```
def get_df_1(self, url=self.url, headers=self.headers, session=self.session):
```

Можно сделать так, тогда если какие-либо параметры не будут заданы, будут использоваться поля объекта:

```
def get_df_1(self, url=None, headers=None, session=None):
    if not url:
        url = self.url

    if not headers:
        headers = self.headers

    if not session:
        session = self.session

    print(url)
    print(headers)
    print(session)
```

Вариант без параметров, просто используем поля объекта:

```
def get_df_1(self):
    print(self.url)
    print(self.headers)
    print(self.session)
```

Comment: всеравно не работает

Comment: @Series_Sam, обновил ответ

Comment: t = mono
t.get_df_1()


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [64], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 t.get_df_1()

TypeError: get_df_1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: `t = mono` это не создание объекта, в `t` у вас класс `mono`. Используйте `t = mono()`

Comment: Понятно спасибо!)

Comment: @Series_Sam, пожалуйста :) Не забудьте принять ответ :)